# Can one make Code Analysis understand Code Contracts?

Tags: c#, code-analysis, code-contracts

When using Code Analysis and Code Contracts in combination, I get a lot of warnings like

[CA1062](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182182.aspx): Microsoft.Design : In externally visible method 'Foo.Bar(Log)', validate parameter 'log' before using it.

In Foo.Bar, I have a contract that validates `log`.

```
public Bar(Log log)
{
   Contract.Requires(log != null);
   log.Lines.Add(...);
   // ...
}
```

Is there a way to make FxCop understand code contracts?

Comment: I expect that you could write an FxCop addin to do the job.

Comment: Terje Sandstrom has a great blog entry that answers this: http://geekswithblogs.net/terje/archive/2010/10/14/making-static-code-analysis-and-code-contracts-work-together-or.aspx

Comment: @Angerico Cariño I've updated the blogpost mentioned above with some new information regarding workarounds for this issue.

Comment: @Dan: As of Framework V4.5.2 it **is** possible to inform CodeAnalysis of how to understand CodeContracts. see my answer at this post and at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13273842/code-contracts-code-analysis/31638749#31638749

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No I do not think it's possible in the current build as the code generated by the contracts rewriter does not produce the standard pattern that FxCop is looking for.

Typically though I disable this particular FxCop rule when using code contracts.  I find the static verifier more than makes up for the loss of this rule as it will yell about a lack of checking much more aggressively than FxCop.  I would suggest the same approach here which will fix this problem for you.

Comment: To actually make this work, you have to perform several tasks:     1. Disable CA1062 in Code Analysis - 2. Enable "Perform Static Contract Checking" in the Code Contracts pane of the project. - **3. Enable "Implicit Non-Null Obligations" - 4. Set Warning Level to "hi" (important, that was what I was missing!)**

Comment: As of version 4.5.2 of the framework it is possible to directly inform Code Analysis of the Code Contracts being enforced. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [as noted in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13273842/code-contracts-code-analysis/31638749#31638749), as of version 4.5.2 of the framework (possibly 4.5) it is possible to inform Code Analysis of the Code Contracts being enforced. An extension method and a marker attribute class must be defined like this:

```
  public static class ContractExtensions {
    /// <summary>Throws <c>ContractException{name}</c> if <c>value</c> is null.</summary>
    /// <param name="value">Value to be tested.</param>
    /// <param name="name">Name of the parameter being tested, for use in the exception thrown.</param>
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA1801:ReviewUnusedParameters", MessageId = "value")]
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA1801:ReviewUnusedParameters", MessageId = "name")]
    [ContractAbbreviator] // Requires Assemble Mode = Standard Contract Requires
    public static void ContractedNotNull<T>([ValidatedNotNull]this T value, string name) where T : class {
      Contract.Requires(value != null,name);
    }
  }

/// <summary>Decorator for an incoming parameter that is contractually enforced as NotNull.</summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class ValidatedNotNullAttribute : global::System.Attribute {}
```

Additional details are in my other answer.

Comment: Although it's a nice solution, it's not "informing code analysis about code contracts". It's a clever trick, that moves all violations into one place (the `ContractedNotNull` method) and suppresses the warning there.

Comment: @BartoszKP: Although I see your point, it still walks and quacks like a duck; forgive me if I call it a duck.

Answer (score -2):

Specify the ArgumentNullException exception like this:

```
public Bar(Log log)
{
   Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(log != null);
   log.Lines.Add(...);
   // ...
}
```

Fxcop expects to to throws the ArgumentNullException exception...

Comment: this works with fxcop and also with code analysis (premium and ultimate).

Comment: This does not work with CA - using the 'Microsoft All Rules' rule set, CA1062 is still raised as a warning.  VS 2010 sp1, Code Contracts 1.4.40314.1

Comment: @felickz This still raises CA1062 under VS2012

Comment: @BryanAnderson: As of version 4.5.2 of the framework it is possible to directly inform Code Analysis of the Code Contracts being enforced. Check out my answer above.