# Incorrect Code Contracts Warnings

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I have recently added code contracts to a very large project. After working my way through a few hundred warnings adding assertions to pacify the checker I am left with some warnings which appear to be obviously incorrect! This probably the most simple example I can make (full code is [here](https://bitbucket.org/martindevans/base-citygeneration/src/d19342154e2e614b4efb53cd689620bd61cf8916/Base-CityGeneration/Elements/Building/Design/Spec/BaseFloorSelector.cs?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#BaseFloorSelector.cs-22), if you think the details may be important):

```
protected Thing DoStuff(A a)
{
    Contract.Requires(a != null);
    //CodeContracts: Consider adding the postcondition Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Thing>() == null); to provide extra-documentation to the library clients

    D outResult;
    var result = DoSomething(a, out outResult);
    if (result == null)
        return null;

    return new Thing(outResult, result);
}
```

This suggestion is quite clearly wrong (I have unit tests which return non-null values from this function to prove it)! The only way it could be true is if "DoSomething" also always returns null, but it is not making any suggestion regarding that.

Edit: I have fixed the above problem by totally rewriting the DoSomething method to not use an out result (instead it returns tuple containing both outResult and result). However I still have other false warnings which I would like to solve and probably have the same root cause.

So really this is two questions:

1. Am *I* doing something wrong or missing something obvious here?
2. Assuming CC is simply *wrong* is there anything I can do to mitigate this kind of problem in the future - at the very least hide the warning!

Comment: Have you tried the form `if (result == null) {
    return null;
}
else
{
    return new Thing(output, result);
}`

Comment: Just tried that, no effect.

Comment: If, instead of returning immediately, you assign the return values to a variable, does the result change? The contract code might be thrown by what some consider to be the bad practice of having multiple return statements. I'm making this suggestion because I note that the first return statement returns null.

Comment: How about forming a contract that either result is null or result has some specific properties `Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Thing>() == null || Contract.Result<Thing>().Result != null)`. Note I can't access bitbucket from my current location, so I dunno how to access the members of `Thing`

Comment: @David I use multiple returns all over my code, it can't be that confusing it. Rather I rewrote it to not use an out parameter, and that fixed instead.

Comment: Unfortunately Code Contracts raises a lot of false positives. (In my experience it has gotten a lot worse over the past couple of years.) It's possible to suppress code contract *warnings* but in your case you're getting a *suggestion*, not a warning. Does the suggestion come with a code (ex: CA2214)?

Comment: @Keith I've rearranged the code to "fix" the errors for now so I can't get the message code, but at least some of the messages I was getting were false positive *warnings*. How do I suppress them?

Comment: I *think* you can right-click the warning in the error list and choose to suppress it which will add a `SupressMessage` attribute to the method. If not, then you can add the attribute manually. Check out the example used in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31638967/65775).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Re : Contract.Ensures on the return value**

In both your MVCE and production code, following the 'burden of proof' upstream, the issue will almost certainly be with the called `SelectScript` extension method (or `DoSomething` in the MVCE), where the static analyzer has inferred (possibly incorrectly) that the extension method always returns null, and hence that in the calling method `SelectSingle` that the first branch (also returning null) would always be chosen, hence the recommended postcondition for null.

I can't find your code for `SelectScript`, but on VS 2013 update 4 / CC 1.7.11202.10, I can only repeat the Contracts warning by explicitly returning only null from `SelectScript` and enabling the "Infer ensures" static checking option, OR by explicitly adding a `Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<ScriptReference>() == null);` to `SelectScript`, e.g. with ensures inference on:

```
public static ScriptReference SelectScript(
    this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<float, KeyValuePair<string, string>[]>> tags,
    Func<double> random,
    Func<KeyValuePair<string, string>[], Type[], ScriptReference> finder,
    out KeyValuePair<string, string>[] selectedTags,
    Type t)
{
    selectedTags = null;
    return null;
}
```

Produces the same warning in the calling method `SelectSingle`:

> CodeContracts: Consider adding the postcondition Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result() == null); to provide extra-documentation to the library clients

However, for me, the analyzer does appear to correctly infer that the below code has branches which both return null, and non-null, and doesn't recommend the precondition in the caller:

```
    public static ScriptReference SelectScript(
        this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<float, KeyValuePair<string, string>[]>> tags,
        Func<double> random,
        Func<KeyValuePair<string, string>[], Type[], ScriptReference> finder,
        out KeyValuePair<string, string>[] selectedTags,
        Type t)
    {
        Contract.Requires(random != null);

        selectedTags = null;
        return (random() > 0.5)
            ? null
            : new ScriptReference();
    }
```

**Re : Contract.Ensures on the out value**

Out of interest, it is also possible to add contracts to `out` parameters, by using `Contract.ValueAtReturn` - 
[reference](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/userdoc.pdf), section 2.2.3 p8.

e.g. If you are still receiving the warning on the *out* parameter, you could use grek40's idea to suppress the warnings in the caller by adding this to `SelectScript`:

```
 Contract.Ensures(Contract.ValueAtReturn(out selectedTags) == null ||
                  Contract.ValueAtReturn(out selectedTags) != null);
```

Comment: Code for SelectScripts (at the appropriate version) is here https://bitbucket.org/martindevans/base-citygeneration/src/a947e8ba4009c34c0b380893668a75ffcb289a36/Base-CityGeneration/Utilities/TagContainer.cs?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#TagContainer.cs-127

Comment: I suspect the error condition at the end of the loop may be confusing CC somehow. I early exit out of the loop when successful but perhaps CC is seeing that the method always ends with tags=null?

Comment: Hmm, I missed the `Contract.ValueAtReturn` method in the manual. That's nifty that that can be used for `out` params (if/when you're forced to use them by the framework or someone else's framework).